# Update HashMap within onERC721Received with Vyper

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, nft, contract-debugging, vyper

When a contract receives an NFT by calling `safeTransferFrom`, `onERC721Received` is automatically called on the receiving contract. **I want to be able to update a Hashmap to record the address of the sender and the NFT token ID when a contract receives an NFT by modifying the `onERC721Received` function**.

Here, calling `setOwner` works as expected:

```py
ownerMapping: HashMap[address, DynArray[uint256, 3]]

@external
def setOwner(newAddress:address, nft:uint256):
    self._setOwner(newAddress, nft)
    
@internal
def _setOwner(newAddress:address, nft:uint256):
    #set a new owner
    self.ownerMapping[newAddress].append(nft)
```

but when I try to call `_setOwner` in the `onERC721Received` function by sending an NFT to the contract using `safeTransferFrom` the transaction reverts:

```py
ownerMapping: HashMap[address, DynArray[uint256, 3]]

@external
def onERC721Received(_operator: address,_from: address,_tokenId: uint256,_data: Bytes[1024]) -> bytes4:
    self._setOwner(_from, _tokenId)
    return method_id("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)", output_type=bytes4)
    
@internal
def _setOwner(newAddress:address, nft:uint256):
    #set a new owner
    self.ownerMapping[newAddress].append(nft)
```

if I directly call `onERC721Received`, then `_setOwner` is called successfully. It is only when `onERC721Received` is called by sending an NFT to the contract via `safeTransferFrom` that the transaction reverts.

Here is the `safeTransferFrom` function along with the interface from the ERC721 token standard I am using (from [here](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/blob/c71b0238bb8e804072a92f7ebc39cbafdb5da3e7/examples/tokens/ERC721.vy#L256)). You can see that `onERC721Received` is called :

```py
interface ERC721Receiver:
    def onERC721Received(
            _operator: address,
            _from: address,
            _tokenId: uint256,
            _data: Bytes[1024]
        ) -> bytes4: view
        
def safeTransferFrom(
        _from: address,
        _to: address,
        _tokenId: uint256,
        _data: Bytes[1024]=b""
    ):
    self._transferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenId, msg.sender)
    if _to.is_contract: # check if `_to` is a contract address
        returnValue: bytes4 = ERC721Receiver(_to).onERC721Received(msg.sender, _from, _tokenId, _data)
        # Throws if transfer destination is a contract which does not implement 'onERC721Received'
        assert returnValue == method_id("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)", output_type=bytes4)
```

Comment: Is the `safeTransferFrom` function calling `onERC721Received`?

Comment: @PatrickCollins question updated for clairty. Btw your smart contract video course is great! thanks

Comment: @PatrickCollins yes it is being called, but is reverting when I 'sneak' in the line `self._setOwner(_from, _tokenId)`

Comment: also reverts if I put `self.ownerMapping[_from].append(_tokenId)` before the return statement in `onERC721Received`. Updating a HashMap shouldn't affect the value that is returned, so it is not clear why it is reverting

Comment: I am quite certain I've found the problem: in the ERC721 token standard the `ERC721Receiver` interface 
 has a `view` annotation, ensuring there can be no storage alterations during execution. So when I try to modify a HashMap it reverts.

Comment: Yep, I think you're right. Interesting, the actual EIP doesn't have the view keyword: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721

Comment: Perhaps we should make an issue on the vyper repo to update this

Comment: Any update here? Did you just remove the `view` keyword?

Comment: @PatrickCollins this was fixed: https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/pull/3076